# Adafruit Feather M0 Basic Proto doesn't show up

Tags: adafruit, arduino-zero

I bought a Feather M0 basic from Amazon [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01BMRCFA2). I installed all the board definitions and stuff from [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-feather-m0-basic-proto/setup) I restarted the IDE and when I plugged it in, the Feather doesn't show up in ports or device manager. I am using a data cable that I verified. Debug is off and USB stack is Arduino.

I also tried following the instructions [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-feather-m0-basic-proto/feather-help) but it didn't work.

When I double-clicked the reset button, the red LED didn't pulse.

Is there anything that am I missing?

**Edit**: Feather is supplying 3~ volts. USB is supplying 4.5~ volts.

**Edit 2**: Charing LED lights up when li-poly is plugged in.

Comment: it could be that you are missing the bootloader. I don't see SWD pins on this board. that would be the way to flash a bootloader. return it

Comment: there are swdio and swclk pads on the bottom of the feather.

Comment: ok. do you have a programmer or other SAMD board?

Comment: if it is possible to use an external programmer for the feather, i'll go for it.

Comment: it must support SWD

Comment: could i use an arduino uno as isp?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95880/discussion-between-unsigned-arduino-and-juraj).

Comment: Why would you buy from that seller? The picture for the sale is for a mattress! What makes you think they have even the *slightest* clue what they are doing?

Comment: They changed the picture after I bought it